# Do I have to commit node_modules in order to run GitLab .gitlab-ci.yml builds?

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Trying to create a .gitlab-ci.yml file to do builds in GitLab.

All attempts thus far fail.

Few examples I am able to find and those seem to have node_modules saved to the repository and use of Docker.

I've no knowledge about Docker.

Are Docker and storing node_modules required in order to perform builds on GitLab? (We don't store the node_modules)?

Here is the entirety of the script which is minimalist and does not work.

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
- build

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build

  script:
    # - npm run build_def_fouo
    - ng build -c def-fouo
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
```

With npm I get: npm: command not found

With ng I get: ng: command not found

I'm at a loss.

===updated 05/06/2022

Made a little bit of progress this morning after 51 failed pipelines.
[image: progress]

Here is my latest script but I'm reviewing the logs and will update with information to debug...

```
image: node:14.17.0

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:            # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - setup
  - build

Test:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - npm install  # or `npm install` or whatever you use to install deps

Builder:
  stage: build
                  
  script:          # ... your other build steps here
    - npm run build_def_fouo
```

=== Error Log

> Error:
> node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/components/button/ng2-dropdown-button.d.ts:18:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/builds/elijah.d.j.marshall/ghostshot/node_modules/@angular/core/core"'
> has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question. NO I DON'T NEED TO SAVE TO GIT THE node_modules diroectory.

This is my file that I got working.

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# To contribute improvements to CI/CD templates, please follow the Development guide at: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html
# This specific template is located at: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Getting-Started.gitlab-ci.yml
# For more information, see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#stages
# START of file content below.
image: node:14.17.0 # This is the container for our Docker we will build in

cache:
  paths:
    - dist/
    - node_modules/

stages:            # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - install_dependencies
  - install_angular
  - build
  - test

install_dep:
  stage: install_dependencies
  image: node:14
  script: # Execute script commands just as you would on terminal command line
    - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - npm install
    - echo npm --version

  artifacts: # This is required for other stage to have access to what gets created
    paths:
      - node_modules/

install_ang:
  stage: install_angular
  image: node:14
  script:
    - npm install -D typescript @angular/cli@12.2.16 @angular/compiler@12.2.16

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - npm run build_def_fouo
    - ls dist/
    - echo "Compile complete."

  artifacts: # This is required for other stage to have access to what gets created
    paths:
      - dist/

.post:
  stage: test # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd65.deb
    - apt install -y ./google-chrome*.deb
    - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    # - sleep 60
    # - echo "Code coverage is 90%"
    - test -f "/node_modules/"
    - npm run test -- --no-watch --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI

# test_async:
#     script:
#         - npm install
#         - node ./specs/start.js ./specs/async.spec.js

# lint-test-job:   # This job also runs in the test stage.
#   stage: test    # It can run at the same time as unit-test-job (in parallel).
#   script:
#     - echo "Linting code... This will take about 10 seconds."
#     - sleep 10
#     - echo "No lint issues found."

# deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
#   stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
#   script:
#     - echo "Deploying application..."
#     - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you would install your dependencies as part of your job. You *could* also form a custom docker image for building your software, but this is not necessary.

```yaml
build-job:
  stage: build
  image: node:lts # this image includes npm/yarn/etc
                  # you can use different tags for different versions
  script:
    - yarn install  # or `npm install` or whatever you use to install deps
    # ... your other build steps here
```

You can find examples for nodejs and many other scenarios in the [examples documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/).

Comment: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-06T09_08_19_332Z-debug-0.log
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: This error comes when your local node/angular environment is different from the build system's environment. Can you double check that?

Comment: How exactly would I specify the Angular environment in the .yml file? My system is Angular CLI: 11.2.13,
Node: 14.17.0

Comment: I think this is how... under the script: - npm install -g @angular/cli@11.2.13